# Solving of differential equation with variable coefficients

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential

I have following differential equation:

$
ode := \\
{\frac { \left(  \left( - 0.7215- 0.09954\,y \left( x \right) 
 \right) {\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}x}}y \left( x \right) + 0.1074\,y
 \left( x \right) + 0.0222\, \left( y \left( x \right)  \right) ^{2}
 \right)  \left( \cos \left( 6\,x \right)  \right) ^{3}+ \left( 
 \left(  \left( - 1.2765- 0.1287\,y \left( x \right)  \right) {\frac 
{\rm d}{{\rm d}x}}y \left( x \right) + 0.5766\,y \left( x \right) +
 0.03108\, \left( y \left( x \right)  \right) ^{2} \right) \sin
 \left( 6\,x \right) + \left(  0.18+ 0.0504\,y \left( x \right) 
 \right) {\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}x}}y \left( x \right) - 134.55- 0.63\,
 \left( y \left( x \right)  \right) ^{2}- 20.916\,y \left( x \right) 
 \right)  \left( \cos \left( 6\,x \right)  \right) ^{2}+ \left( 
 \left(  \left( - 1.695- 0.357\,y \left( x \right)  \right) {\frac 
{\rm d}{{\rm d}x}}y \left( x \right) - 81.0- 0.924\,y \left( x
 \right) + 0.3048\, \left( y \left( x \right)  \right) ^{2} \right) 
\sin \left( 6\,x \right) + \left(  1.32525+ 0.41895\,y \left( x
 \right)  \right) {\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}x}}y \left( x \right) + 12.42-
 3.0795\,y \left( x \right) - 0.1749\, \left( y \left( x \right) 
 \right) ^{2} \right) \cos \left( 6\,x \right) + \left(  \left( -
 0.34125- 0.23175\,y \left( x \right)  \right) {\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}x
}}y \left( x \right) + 1.1355\,y \left( x \right) - 7.02+ 0.2037\,
 \left( y \left( x \right)  \right) ^{2} \right) \sin \left( 6\,x
 \right) + \left(  0.2835\,y \left( x \right) + 0.6825 \right) {\frac 
{\rm d}{{\rm d}x}}y \left( x \right) + 9.78\,y \left( x \right) +
 0.273\, \left( y \left( x \right)  \right) ^{2}+ 67.275}{ 36.4\,
 \left( \cos \left( 6\,x \right)  \right) ^{3}+ \left(  122.0\,\sin
 \left( 6\,x \right) - 144.0 \right)  \left( \cos \left( 6\,x \right) 
 \right) ^{2}+ \left(  420.0\,\sin \left( 6\,x \right) - 525.0
 \right) \cos \left( 6\,x \right) + 325.0\,\sin \left( 6\,x \right) -
 350.0}} = 0
$

If I try to solve it with Maple:

```
dsolve(ode, y(x))
```

...the solver doesn't come to an end.

I'm aware that the equation is complex (it is called a differential equation with variable coefficients, correct?) but is there maybe a special "trick" for such a equation?

I assume that the "problems" here are the trigonometric functions, correct?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's not just the variable coefficients, but the nonlinearity as well, that makes this difficult.

Comment: Why are you sure that a symbolic solution exists? There are lots of simple ODE, even of first order, that do not have symbolic solutions. Like $y'=y^2+\cos(x)$ or other Riccati equations. Some you can reduce to a normal form and then give the solutions of that normal form a name, but still that is not really a symbolic solution in elementary functions.

Comment: @LutzL I'm not completely sure, but I have the idea/basis for this calculation from a paper, where the author said that it is possible to solve this "analytically".